# EXTJS 5 - How to disable certain items in a menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I am using a menu to display a number of options for rows in my grid. The menu displays the text correctly and I want to be able to disable some of these options dynamically.

This is my menu:

```
Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
items: [{
    text: 'option 1'
},{
    text: 'option 2'
},{
    text: 'option 3'
}]
});
```

I've tried giving each item an id and disabling it by id but I get an error in my console saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined(…)
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var menu=Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
items: [{
    text: 'option 1'
},{
    text: 'option 2'
},{
    text: 'option 3'
}]
});
var item=menu.getComponent(//index of the item)
item.setDisabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to call method [disable](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.menu.Item.html#method-disable) on the [menuitem](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.menu.Item.html).

```
var item = Ext.first('#mySpecialMenuItem');
item.disable();
```

Something like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'menu',
    floating: false,
    id: 'myMenu',
    width: 120,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'menuitem',
            id: 'mySpecialMenuItem',
            text: 'Menu Item'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'menuitem',
            text: 'Menu Item'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'menuitem',
            text: 'Menu Item'
        }
    ]
},
{
    xtype: 'button',
    handler: function(button, e) {
        // somehow get the item
        var item = Ext.first('#mySpecialMenuItem');
        // call disable
        item.disable();

    },
    text: 'Disable Item'
}
```

Check the full example in this fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1m2q